# SQL Null values and non-Null values

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID (pk,int)
Col1 (nvarchar)
Col2 (nvarchar)
Col3 (nvarchar)
```

In all columns (except ID) some values are NULL.

I want to make a query that will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE (Col1=<parameter> AND Col1 IS NULL)
 +    (Col2=<parameter> AND Col2 IS NULL)
etc.
```

I need values that are NULL and that are equal to parameter

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, specifically the bit "I need values that are NULL and that are equal to parameter", makes no sense. The where clause:

```
Col1 = <parameter> AND Col1 IS NULL
```

will *never* be true, since a column is either NULL *or* something. It can't be both at the same time.

If you mean you want values that are equal to the parameter *OR* NULL, you should use:

```
Col1 = <parameter> OR Col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I made a mistake in my question and you are right.
But, this yor example works with only one column. If I put second column (AND Col2 LIKE<parameter> OR Col2 IS NULL) then it gives me only the results from Col2 that are Null or only the results from Col2 that are <parameter> (never both).
I know that this sounds complicated, but i need values from 2 or more columns that are in all columns both null and <parameter>.

Maybe it's a syntax problem. Here is what i've typed in SSME:

WHERE (Col1='5' or Col1 IS NULL) AND (Col2 IS NULL OR Col2 LIKE N'P')

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `AND` with `OR` in your `WHERE` statements.

```
WHERE (Col1=<parameter> OR Col1 IS NULL)
ANd   (Col2=<parameter> OR Col2 IS NULL)
```